# Neo4j - Enterprise Edition Features

Tags: scala, neo4j, graph-databases

I was using Neo4j community edition along with Scala with Scala-Neo4j wrapper and I just downloaded the Enterprise edition of Neo4j. I saw some of the additional features in Enterprise edition like High-Performance Cache, Clustering and 3* Production Instances. How do I make use of these features? Do I need to make any changes to the code which I wrote while using the community edition to make use of these features?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your deployment model.

If you use Neo4j in embedded mode you typically initialize the DB using `GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(path)`. When going for Neo4j Enterprise embedded you have to replace that by `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder(path).setConfig(map).newGraphDatabase()` where `map` contains the config settings for your deployment, esp the ha parameters documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html.

In case of a deployment where your application accesses Neo4j via REST (server deployment) you don't should change the URL your accessing to the loadbalancer's URL.

Please note that Neo4j enterprise is dual licensed: AGPL (affero-GPL) or commercial license, see http://www.neo4j.org/learn/licensing for more on this.

Comment: I am using Neo4j in embedded mode. Can I get any explanation of the features that I mentioned in my question(High-Performance Cache, Clustering and 3* Production Instances).

Comment: It's all in the reference manual, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha.html for Clustering and http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/operations-backup.html for online backup and http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_object_cache for GC resistant cache (aka high perf cache).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite an old question but others may find this useful. It is possible to use the Scala Neo4j Wrapper with an HA instance.

You can extend `GraphDatabaseServiceProvider`. To get the enterprise features such as clustering you will need to run an instance of your application on each cluster node.

```
package graphdatabase

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

import eu.fakod.neo4jscala.{
  Neo4jWrapper, DatabaseService,
  DatabaseServiceImpl, GraphDatabaseServiceProvider
}

import org.neo4j.cluster.ClusterSettings
import org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HaSettings
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory

object HighAvailabilityGraphDatabase extends Neo4jWrapper with GraphDatabaseServiceProvider {

  def neo4jStoreDir = "/path/to/db"

  // The config params will vary for each cluster node.
  // You could use environment variables for example to configure.
  def configParams = Map(
    ClusterSettings.server_id.name -> sys.env.get("SERVER_ID").get, // e.g. 1
    HaSettings.ha_server.name -> sys.env.get("HA_SERVER").get, // e.g. server1:6001
    ClusterSettings.cluster_server.name -> sys.env.get("CLUSTER_SERVER").get, // e.g.server1:5001
    ClusterSettings.initial_hosts.name -> sys.env.get("INITIAL_HOSTS").get // e.g. server1:5001,server2:5001
  )

  val ds: DatabaseService = {
    val gdb = DatabaseServiceImpl(new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()
      .newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder(neo4jStoreDir)
      .setConfig(mapAsJavaMap(configParams))
      .newGraphDatabase
    )
    sys.addShutdownHook({
      shutdown(gdb)
    })
    gdb
  }
}
```

You should also be able to configure high performance caching in the configuration although I'd check [the docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_object_cache) for that

You can then use the Neo4j Scala wrapper as you would anywhere else by importing from `HighAvailabilityGraphDatabase`. But you can now get the benefit of other enterprise features such as live backups. It's also easy to access the underlying Java database service from the Scala wrapper.

```
import graphdatabase.HighAvailabilityGraphDatabase._

object Foo {
  withTx { implicit db =>
    // use db.gds to access the underlying GraphDatabaseService object.
    // otherwise create nodes etc as per usual.
    val node = createNode
    node("foo") = "bar"
  }
}
```

**Note:** You'll also need to ensure that you include Neo4j HA in your build.sbt (or similar) since it isn't included in the Scala wrapper.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-ha" % "2.1.3" // Replace 2.1.3 with your version
)
```